# Fine for first user but error for third user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top
I've followed all steps exactly, so that will show you all of my relevant code.

I got the application to work, for the first user. That said, I added three users to the application I made, and it won't work for the third user. I'm wondering what I did wrong in order for that error message to occur. Here's what I did:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.0.0-p353 :001 > first_user = User.first
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, first: "John", last: "Palfrey", email: "jpalfrey@andover.edu", status: "Confused as to why he's on Claire's application.", created_at: "2013-12-21 18:53:17", updated_at: "2013-12-21 18:53:17"> 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > first_user.microposts
Micropost Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Micropost id: 1, content: "This is rather odd.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-12-21 18:56:58", updated_at: "2013-12-21 18:56:58">, #<Micropost id: 3, content: "I hope Claire can figure this out, for the sake of ...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-12-21 18:57:32", updated_at: "2013-12-21 18:57:32">]> 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > third_user = User.third
NoMethodError: undefined method `third' for #<Class:0x007fac91453928>
from /Users/Brawain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
from (irb):3
from /Users/Brawain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/Brawain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/Brawain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? If you want to see my gem file, my models, and such, just check the link I provided above!

Thanks in advance,
~Janie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method as `User.third`, you can use: `User.find(3)` where 3 is the id of the third user.

If you are not sure that the id of the third User is 3, then you can do:

```
User.take(3).last
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad that I didn't write my code wrong. Just tested it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such method as `.third`, only `.first` and `.last`.  You'll want to try `User.find(3)`, which is looking up the users by their ID.

You'll find this useful - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html